# Codeigniter URI strings | How to show 404 if not equal to a letter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I am creating a glossary for my website that will display definitions for terms on my site.

I have everything working. But I would like to **show a 404 if my uri segment 3 contains anything other than the letters in the alphabet**.

My glossary urls currently look like:

```
www.mydomain.com/tools/glossary/a
www.mydomain.com/tools/glossary/b
www.mydomain.com/tools/glossary/c
...
```

I want to show a 404 if the user enters a string that is not in the alphabet:

example

```
www.mydomain.com/tools/glossary/tree
```

In my glossary function I have added the following:

```
        if($this->uri->segment(3)) {
            if($this->uri->segment(3) !== 'a' || 'b' || 'c' .... 'z') {
                show_404();
            }
        }
```

How can I get the above code to work??

Show a 404 if the 3rd uri segment does not equal a letter between a and z??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this (controller tools.php)

```
  function glossary($letter)  
  {
   if(!preg_match('/^[a-z]$/',$letter))
    {
       show_404();
    }
    else
    {
      echo 'match';
      //do something with $letter
    }
   }
```

Tests:

```
a  'match'
b  'match'
ab  404
1   404
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using "[Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)"

Also consider a 301 redirect instead of a 404, might help with SEO.

HTH.

Comment: According to this page:
http://www.seomoz.org/blog/are-404-pages-always-bad-for-seo

It's not always a good idea to 301 redirect 404 errors. Unless the URL generating the 404 error either: a) supports a lot of traffic, b) has important external links to it, or c) has an obvious URL that users would type in by themselves, the document recommends to leave a 404 error as it is, displaying it properly, of course (a nice 404 page).

Answer (score 0):

I don't use PHP but isn't || an OR operator? You need an AND operator there.